# Does $a=\frac{\langle x,y\rangle}{\| y \|^2}$ imply $\| a \| =\frac{\| x \|}{\| y \|}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, inner-products

As the title, um, $\overset{?}{\text{suggests}}$ I'm wondering if $a=\frac{\langle x,y\rangle}{\lVert y \rVert^2}\overset{\color{pink} \heartsuit}{\implies}\lvert a \rvert=\frac{\lVert x \rVert}{\lVert y \rVert}$. So what do you think?

EDIT$^1$:

Where $z=x-ay$ and $y$ and $z$ are orthogonal, with $y\neq 0$ and assuming that
$$\lvert \langle x,y\rangle \rvert = \lVert x \rVert \cdot \lVert y \rVert.$$

---

Perhaps this literature may be of help:

[image]

EDIT$^2$:

OK, I think I've got it know. Thank you for everyone's kind and considerate help.

Comment: And yes, the implication *must* be one that is loving.

Comment: Oh, oops. I meant to mention the specifics.

Comment: 100%-LaTeX titles create problems for some users (it's impossible to open them in a new tab via right-click). "Does $A$ imply $B$?" is safer to use than "$A\overset{?}{\implies} B$".

Comment: Do not use `\mid` for absolute value. Compare the spacings: $\mid a\mid = \mid b \mid$ (incorrect) and $\lvert a \rvert = \lvert b \rvert$ (correct).

Comment: Seriously, "right-click here"? You didn't consider actually writing out the word "imply"? By Jove...

Comment: As it happens Mr. J, yes, seriously...

Comment: Your formatting of your question looks like a huge mess to me. You have unnecessary symbols included and some unnecessary language (e.g.  "um"). Plus, you say "What do you think"? Did *you* try thinking about it? You don't show us any attempt at the problem which can make it easier for people to help you. Furthermore, you provide things to aid people to solve this problem *for* you. I think that is rude. Do you really think people don't know the Cauchy Schwarz inequality on here? It's unnecessary.

Comment: Also, concerning edits: when you edit in missing information from the question I think it's best to edit it in directly to the problem statement. I think editing in thank you to anyone is also unnecessary and instead can be done in the comments if you'd like to show your appreciation. I just think the space you have for the question should be left uncluttered with the question clearly stated and with your attempt or with reasoning so that people may help you better. Please take this into consideration for next time.

Comment: @BryanUrízar I didn't read your messages, but I did think about it yes. I use stackexchange as a medium to see things through others eyes. For most of the questions I ask I have an outline in front of me of how I think it'll go. I'm just wondering about you Mr. Bryan, how are things going? I mean with your life? Are you pretty happy?

Comment: Well, it seems like you can't take any criticism. Thanks for asking about how my life is going, but quite frankly that is none of your concern. Thanks anyways.

Comment: I can take criticism. I'm just a brusque character.

Answer (score 5):

No. If $x\perp y$, then $a=0$ even if $x\neq 0$.

If $\lvert\langle x,y\rangle\rvert=\lVert x\rVert \lVert y\rVert$ (that is, $x,y$ are colinear), then certainly $\lvert a\rvert=\frac{\lVert x\rVert}{\lVert y\rVert}$.

Not sure about the loving part, though.

Comment: Yeah, the loving part was just the result of odd mood I'm in.

Answer (score 2):

The correct formula is $\dfrac{\langle x,y\rangle}{\|y\|^2}=\dfrac{\|x\|}{\|y\|}\cos\theta$, where $\theta$ is the angle between $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Nothing I have written is incorrect, on this page.

Comment: How are you doing in life?